# Name for the chat room

Tags: discussion, chat

[It came up in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15519552#15519552) that perhaps we should give a name to the main chat room, like how the main Arqade chat room is called “The Bridge.” Is this a good idea, and if so what names do you recommend?

Answer (score 10):

As I mentioned in my [other answer](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/711/133) about the site name:

### The Practice Room

... in reference to the common experience of musicians of all styles of music!

<sup>And if the site ends up being called **Music: Theory & Practice**, this also becomes a play on "chat room" *and* the site title. ;-)</sup>

Comment: I like that name! Slightly better than the one I posted, in fact.

Comment: This is the highest vote, when will we change it? :D

Comment: @seseorang Done!

Answer (score 9):

[@Dom's suggestion from the chat:](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15521856#15521856)

## The Green Room

The green room is a general term for a room that performers hang out in before they perform.

Comment: This one occurred to me too. So far I like this one second best. I like that it has "room" in the name, for one thing.

Comment: As a non-anglophone, I had no idea what this term meant 10 seconds ago.

Comment: @Édouard See?  This site is so educational!

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative:

## Backstage

Well... backstage.
Although it also fits other performing arts it might fit the bill here. However not every musician is a stage performer and might never be backstage (such as composers, producers, studio musicians, etc). But the chat is kind of backstage to the main site.

Comment: This one has a bit more personality, I like it.

Comment: I like this for a "site meta" type of room.

Answer (score 5):

The same discussion came up with the suggestion of calling our main chat room:

## The Pit

. . . in reference to orchestra pits and mosh pits.

Comment: Nice getting to vote for my own name :P

Comment: My immediate association is with holes leading to oblivion ... so my -1, sorry!

Comment: @Matthew No worries, I personally like the Practice Room myself! Posted this because it was suggested in chat.

Answer (score 2):

## The Grapevine

... in reference to the song.

Answer (score 1):

Or we could add something like

**Sgt Peppers Lonely Hearts Chat Band**

(:P)

Comment: I actually kinda like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

What about

## Symphony

Because of its Greek roots: συν (sun - u pronounced like German ü) = together and φωνή (foni) = voice.

### Edit:

I mixed some words up, luckily shevliaskovic caught it. Turns out it is an even better fit, in a chat room voices are together. (Bit awkwardly phrased, my English is not perfect either.)

Comment: Actually, φόνος means murder :P The word 'Symphony' comes from the words 'Συν' and 'Φωνή' (Φωνή means voice)

Comment: Whoops, this is not the first time I mix those up! Feel free to edit! Good thing I may use a dictionary in class. @Shevliaskovic

Answer (score 0):

Or an alternative:

**The Jam**

Not the band, but the session where everyone contributes

Comment: Classical musicians don't 'jam' :P

Comment: There are improvisation competitions though. However, these aren't very common. @AmericanLuke

Answer (score 0):

**The Music Room** seems fairly apposite to me! If we've got one, we're lucky. if we haven't most of us would like one...