# Music SE is getting a new name -- Music: Practice & Theory

Tags: discussion

As soon as we announced that Music SE would be [graduating](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/music-se-is-graduating-congratulations), the community mobilized to get the site name changed to better reflect how music, as a discipline, gets explored in Q&A around here. Now, after a good deal of debate, a new name has been selected. Upon graduation the name 'Musical Practice & Performance' will be no more.

### This site's official name will become Music: Practice & Theory.

This post serves as an official announcement. If you're wondering why this name was chosen, have a look at [these](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/931/7392) [two](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/960/7392) answers to the recent 'Site Rename Poll'.

Thanks to everyone who weighed in.

Comment: Good news! When will the change be into effect? Is there a defined date for it?

Comment: 6-8 weeks, or whenever the next build goes out @SeuMenezes.

Comment: Um. It looks like it just happened!

Comment: @Shog9 fastest 6-8 weeks ever.

Comment: When do we go to non-beta status and get the facelift?

Comment: sooooon, Charles :-)

Comment: I think this needs some more discussion

Comment: Alexander - it has been discussed extensively. Read Ana's comments over on the main post.

Answer (score -7):

I don't think it was clearly publicised that the name had changed from the most popular ***Music:Theory and Practice*** option.  If we're having a decision about the whole site's direction, the whole site should have an equal say!

[Rename the site to Music: Theory and Practice?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/992/updating-site-name-to-theory-and-practice-rather-than-practice-and-theory)

Comment: As discussed, the whole site has an equal say, and this was taken into account by Stack Exchange. They went with our top scoring answer, and slightly tweaked it. It is down to the individual to visit meta (and probably chat) regularly if you are interested in development of the site.

Comment: Thanks doc, I've voiced all my concerns in the related question :)